# Looking for help of Outlook Calendar for day activity in WPF ?

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls, wpfdatagrid

I want to build Outlook Calander in WPF from scratch ,so please give me guidance , what controls should be used for that.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

codeplex has open source schedule control, see http://wpfschedule.codeplex.com/ But it has only daily view.